# Checking columns in R not efficient and too slow. Are there any faster options to function 'interaction'?

Tags: r, csv

I have a CSV file as

h.csv

```
Identity,CampaignName,AdGroupName,State,City
344,return,wewe,utah,los
613,tere,ree,tyt,dlms
6566,sad,ur,ds,pol
```

I have another CSV file as

georeportrecord.csv

```
Campaign,Adgroup
sad,ur
return,reer
```

Desired output

```
Identity,CampaignName,AdGroupName,State,City,CampaignDuplicate,AdGroupDuplicate
344,return,wewe,utah,los,Yes,No
613,tere,ree,tyt,dlms,No,No
6566,sad,ur,ds,pol,Yes,Yes
```

I am checking against the two CSV files to see whether the campaign and the adgroup of the first file is present in the second file or not. If present YES otherwise NO.

My piece of code is

```
Campaigns <- georeportrecord$Campaign
AdGroups <- interaction(georeportrecord$Campaign, georeportrecord$Adgroup)
h$CampaignDuplicate <- ifelse(h$CampaignName %in% Campaigns,"YES","NO")
h$AdGroupDuplicate <- ifelse(interaction(h$CampaignName,h$AdGroupName) %in% AdGroups,"YES","NO")
```

The code works fine, but for a large set of data like 200000 rows for georeportrecord.csv it runs too slowly and never finishes.

How to optimize it for better performance. Any ideas. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are there many duplicate Campaigns? How about many duplicate Campaign x Adgroup combinations?

Comment: @DavidRobinson  There are over 200000 combinations of CampaignName and AdGroupName in georeportrecord.csv, yes there are many duplicate campaigns, so it is checking against each case.right?

Comment: I think you can use the `data.table` package to do binary searching to speed up the process.

Comment: @WetFeet : hey  where is your suggestion, did you delete it?

Comment: @user3188390 I was editing it, sorry.

Comment: @WetFeet Should I be reading the CSV file using fread or just 'read.csv'?

Comment: @user3188390 Ideally this whole program should be converted to use `data.table` functions (`fread` is faster than `read.csv`) but I'm assuming you used `read.csv`. It should work either way though.

Comment: @user3188390: Does changing the first line to `ifelse(h$CampaignName %in% unique(Campaigns),"YES","NO")` help much?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need to use the call to `interaction`.

Using the data.table binary search/join feature will work here.

First make the tables (you'd just put file names to `read.csv` not `text=` like I have):

```
library(data.table)
h <- data.table(read.csv(text='
Identity,CampaignName,AdGroupName,State,City
344,return,wewe,utah,los
613,tere,ree,tyt,dlms
6566,sad,ur,ds,pol', header=T))

georeport <- data.table(read.csv(text='
Campaign,Adgroup
sad,ur
return,reer', header=T))
```

First for `h$CampaignDuplicate`, set the key of `h` and `georeport` to the campaign column and initialize the column to False

```
setkey(georeport, Campaign)
setkey(h, CampaignName)
h[, CampaignDuplicate:=F]
```

Then set `CampaignDuplicate` to T wherever the Campaign column of `h` is in `georeport`.

```
h[georeport, CampaignDuplicate:=T]
#    Identity CampaignName AdGroupName State City CampaignDuplicate
# 1:      344       return        wewe  utah  los              TRUE
# 2:     6566          sad          ur    ds  pol              TRUE
# 3:      613         tere         ree   tyt dlms             FALSE
```

Do pretty much the same thing for AdGroupDuplicate, but just set the key to be the (Campaign, AdGroup) columns combined:

```
setkey(georeport, Campaign, Adgroup)
setkey(h, CampaignName, AdGroupName)
h[, AdGroupDuplicate:=F]
h[georeport, AdGroupDuplicate:=T]
#    Identity CampaignName AdGroupName State City CampaignDuplicate AdGroupDuplicate
# 1:      344       return        wewe  utah  los              TRUE            FALSE
# 2:     6566          sad          ur    ds  pol              TRUE             TRUE
# 3:      613         tere         ree   tyt dlms             FALSE            FALSE
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, but this is slightly different from what I wish the result to be,as mentioned in the example if the campaignname is present and the adgroupname is not present then it should indicate YES for campaignname and NO for the AdGroupname, in the sense after only it sees whether the campaignname is present then it will check for adgroupname

Comment: The AdGroupDuplicate column was the same as what you wished the column to be. I did not realise you needed code for the CampaignDuplicate column too (in your question you say you are checking the CSV files to see if the "campaign and adgroup of the first file is present in the second file or not", which only describes your AdGroupDuplicate column, not the CampaignDuplicate one. Anyhow, I updated it with code for both columns for you.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help, I appreciate your concern and quick reply.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution using `data.table`. I haven't tested it but I think it should work.

```
require(data.table)
## Convert to data.table
Campaigns <- data.table(georeportrecord$Campaign)
AdGroups <- data.table(interaction(georeportrecord$Campaign, georeportrecord$Adgroup))

## Sort table and allow binary searching
setkey(Campaigns,V1) 
setkey(AdGroups,V1)

## Binary Search
h$CampaignDuplicate <- ifelse(h$CampaignName %in% Campaigns$V1,"YES","NO")
h$AdGroupDuplicate <- ifelse(interaction(h$CampaignName,h$AdGroupName) %in% AdGroups$V1,"YES","NO")
```

EDIT: Changed %chin% to %in%

Comment: Ok just wait let me test it.

Comment: Error in h$CampaignName %chin% Campaigns$V1 : 
  x is type 'integer' (must be 'character' or NULL)

Comment: it should be %in% instead of %chin%

Comment: Do you have numeric campaign names? If so, you would have to use %in% instead.

Comment: You aren't actually doing a binary search there.

Comment: @WetFeet I did test it. It is working for small sets not for large sets like 200000 rows. the program never finishes running. Thank you for the help. Any further suggestions?